# Find: $\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{f(a+\frac{1}{n})}{f(a)}\right)^{n}$ as $f$ is differentiable on $x=a$, and $f'(a)=2, f(a)=5$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f$ be defined in the environment of the point $a$. Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $x=a$, and $f'(a)=2,\ f(a)=5$

Find: $$\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{f(a+\frac{1}{n})}{f(a)}\right)^{n}$$

I've tried to use the fact that according to the Differential of a function.

let $a=x_{0}$. If $f$ is differentiable in $x=x_{0}$ than, 
the line:
$$l(x) = f(x_{0}) + f'(x_{0})(x-x_{0})$$ exists: 
$$\lim_{x\longrightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)-l(x)}{x-x_{0}}=0$$

and then  $$\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{f(a+\frac{1}{n})}{f(a)}\right)^{n}=\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{f(a)+f(a+\frac{1}{n})-f(a)}{f(a)}\right)^{n}=l$$

but I didn't managed to get some progress from here.

Comment: Using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Clongrightarrow%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bf(a%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D)%7D%7Bf(a)%7D%5Cright)%5E%7Bn%7D%24&p=1) you can find some related question: [Regarding limits: $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{f(x)}\right)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/704826) and [computing a limit of a function that is positive defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/894226).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that

$$\ln\left(\frac{f\left(a + \frac{1}{n}\right)}{f(a)}\right)^n = \frac{\ln\left(f\left(a + \frac{1}{n}\right)\right) - \ln(f(a))}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

As $n \to \infty$, this tends to the derivative of $\ln \circ f$ at $a$. Using chain rule, this limit comes to
$$\frac{f'(a)}{f(a)} = \frac{2}{5}.$$

However, of course, the original limit is $e^{\frac{2}{5}}$.

Comment: could you explain this transition? as I understand, $ln(x)^{n} = n \ln(x)$

Comment: Sure. I'm also using $\ln(a/b) = \ln(a) - \ln(b)$. So, pulling the $n$ down gives us multiplication by $n$, or equivalently, division by $\frac{1}{n}$. The $\ln\left(\frac{f\left(a + \frac{1}{n}\right)}{f(a)}\right)$ becomes $\ln(f(a + \frac{1}{n})) - \ln(f(a))$, and we're done. As for why this becomes the derivative of $\ln \circ f$, try making the substitution $h = \frac{1}{n}$. As $n \to \infty$, $h \to 0$, and the expression becomes the definition of the derivative of $\ln \circ f$ at $a$.

Comment: amazing!! thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{f(a+\frac{1}{n})}{f(a)}\right)^{n}\\=\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{f(a)+\frac{1}{n}f'(a)+...}{f(a)}\right)^{n}\\=\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}(1+(2/5)(1/n))^n=e^{2/5} $$